# Parsing a string to extract a delimited unit having an alphabetic starting character and and an unknown length

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm new to python regular expression so any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I have this
`string = "Restaurant_Review-g503927-d3864736-Reviews"`

I would like extract 'g503927' and 'd3864736' from it.

I know you can use `re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)`

But not sure how to write the regex for it. Plz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [re.findall](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> s = "Restaurant_Review-g503927-d3864736-Reviews"
>>> re.findall('[a-z]\d+', s)
['g503927', 'd3864736']
```

`[a-z]\d+` matches lowercase alphabet followed by digits.

Comment: To expand on the explanation + means that it looks for "1 or more" of the token before it. This regex also assumes that the letter will be lowercase (which it looks like in your example). If it's ever not that won't work. If OP wants to match uppercase you can change the character set to [A-Za-z]. And last note if there's ever a case where there might be a lowercase letter followed by numbers somewhere else in the name you may want to add `(?<=-)` to the front of that regex.

Comment: How about `\b[a-z]\d+`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("[a-z][0-9]+")
```

Answer (score 0):

a non-regex solution but it depends on what is delimiting the units, here i assume it's a `-`:

```
s = "Restaurant_Review-g503927-d3864736-Reviews"
outputs = [i for i in s.split('-') if i[0].isalpha() and i[1:].isdigit()]
```

Comment: You mean `s.split('-')`? and you can also use `i[:1].isalpha()`, so no index errors for empty strings.

Comment: why would he need `i[1:].isalpha` if his output string only have `alpha` on the first char?

Comment: I used `i[:1].isalpha()` not `i[1:].isalpha()`.

Comment: wahahhaa... yesh, i see now... i was blind...

Answer (score -1):

no need to use Regex... use the `split()` method:

```
s = "Restaurant_Review-g503927-d3864736-Reviews"

print s.split('-')

print s.split('-')[1]
print s.split('-')[2]
```

more info here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: not going to work if `x2352` appears in a different element in `str.split()`

Comment: I don't follow.. where does x2352 come from?

Comment: That must be his extension!